AUTHINFO enrichment and use for securing SDR RCVR channels between 2 distributed QMs
I have 2 Linux VM and 1 Win10 machine on LAN. Ive built QM-A on VM 1 and QM-B on VM 2 in a distributed queuing architecture(bi directional). On top of that I have connected each QM to a MQ Explorer on Win10 machine. The version is 9.3 and everything works smoothly.
I want to add security layer to SDR and RCVR channels so that only specific users that already have access to QM will be able to view messages from the channels. From what I know so far is that I need to build AUTHINFO object, then change the connection of the QM to use that object. But for some reason, I fail to correctly deploy that security layer.
For example, I built a QM and ran those MQSC commands after it:

DEFINE AUTHINFO('LDAP_AUTHINFO') AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP) USRFIELD('uid') SHORTUSR('cn') BASEDNU('ou=users, o=bob, c=ireland') CLASSUSR('inetOrgPerson') LDAPPWD('bob1234') LDAPUSER('cn=jason,ou=users,o=bob,c=ireland')
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH('LDAP_AUTHINFO')
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)

ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(ENABLED)
SET CHLAUTH('SDR') TYPE(USERMAP) CLNTUSER('jason') USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER('LDAP_AUTHINFO') ADDRESS('*') ACTION(ADD)
SET CHLAUTH('RCVR') TYPE(USERMAP) CLNTUSER('jason') USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER('LDAP_AUTHINFO') ADDRESS('*') ACTION(ADD)
SET CHLAUTH('SDR') TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('*') ACTION(ADD)
SET CHLAUTH('RCVR') TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('*') ACTION(ADD)


DEFINE CHANNEL(SOMESENDER) CHLTYPE(SDR) CONNAME('localhost(1800)') TRPTYPE(TCP) XMITQ(ALREADYDEFINED)
START CHANNEL(SOMESENDER)


SOMESENDER channel is accessed from the MQ Explorer and works fine. I tried to get some test messages via ./amqsget command and everything works fine which is incorrect because Im connected to the QM via user named jackson(and not jason).
Is there a correct way to allow LDAP users to VIEW ONLY messages on SDR/RCVR channels? Is there an option to make AUTHINFO object that will allow user+pass authentication based by a specific given list?
thanks in advance for the support

You would not view messages on a SDR channel,  you would view them on a queue.  You would use SET AUTHREC command to provide permission that you require.  AUTHINFO objects are not something you reference in the CHLAUTH rules.   CHLAUTH rules would apply when you receive a connection to the channel from the remote QM, for example the sender channel SOMESENDER points to a receiver channel called SOMESENDER, you would put in a CHLAUTH rule on the receiver.  The name of the CHLAUTH rules world match the channel names or wildcarded names that match channels,  they wouldn't be named SDR or RCVR.

You say you want to allow some users to "view messages from the channels" but there is no record maintained of which channel delivered a message to a queue. Once the message is on the queue, if you access to view messages on the queue, you can see them all, regardless of who put them there.

Thanks for your reply and support, Josh and Morag. If I want to configure an LDAP user to "VIEW ONLY" a specific QM on a random server, then I should be focusing on defining an AUTHINFO object rather than adjusting CHLAUTH rules. This will ensure the user can only view the queues inside that QM. Am I right? If yes, then how is that achievable? Is there any set of MQSC`s that I should follow(I need the most basic one)?
